# Specify manually installed dependency with Synaptic install

Tags: ubuntu, transmission, synaptic-pkg-mgr

Libevent2.0.5 is the latest version available in the repository but I want to use libevent2.0.21 instead as I'm troubleshooting an error with Transmission.  I compiled libevent2.0.21-stable using checkinstall and verified that it shows in Synaptic. I removed libevent2.0.5 using synaptic.  When I attempt to install Tranmission (from repo), I'm being prompted to install the dependancy libevent2.0.5

How do I install Tranmission from repo without having to use an outdated dependancy in the repo as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there may be a misunderstanding. *libevent-2.0-5* is not a package version, it's the name of the package, while the version number is 2.0.21. You can check it as follows:

```
   # apt-cache showpkg libevent-2.0
   Package: libevent-2.0-5
   Versions: 
   2.0.21-stable-1ubuntu1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
   .....
```

We can double-check this: the command *apt-get install packagename=packageversion* installs the specific package version.

```
 # apt-get install libevent-2.0-5
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   libevent-2.0-5 is already the newest version.
   upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
 # apt-get install libevent-2.0-5=2.0.21-stable-1ubuntu1
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   libevent-2.0-5 is already the newest version.
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Your only worry need be that future system updates do not involve *libevent-2.0-5*. You can stick to this version of a package with the following command:

```
 apt-mark hold libevent-2.0-5
```

and then, when you **do** want to to update the package,

```
 apt-mark unhold libevent-2.0-5
```